# How to define a data structure for a list that cannot be empty in F#?

Tags: list, data-structures, f#

Recently, I started learning F# and I am struggling to work with discriminated unions, lists en structures. I'd found an exercise where I need to do the following:

**'Define a NonEmptyList<'a> data structure which can represent a list which can never be empty'**

#### Attempt

```
let NonEmptyList (input : List<'a>) = 
   match input with
   | [] -> failwith "List canot be empty"
   | [x] -> x
```

Not really sure if this is correctly implemented with the let-keyword. I.e... do I need this construction perhaps:

```
type NonEmptyList<'a> = struct
    | List
```

#### edit 1

```
type NonEmptyList<'T> = 
  | Cons of 'T * List<'T>
  | Single of List<'T>
```

#### edit 2

```
let list1 : NonEmptyList<'T> = Single[1..10]
let list2 : NonEmptyList<'T> = Cons([1..3],[1..3])
```

I am receiving a parser error: This construct causes code to be less generic than indicated by the type annotations. The type variable 'T has been constrianed to be type 'a list.

Answer (score 7):

First of all, my reading of the task is to give a type definition (using `type`) rather than a function that checks whether a list is empty.

To solve this, it's best to first understand normal F# lists:

```
type List<'T> = 
  | Cons of 'T * List<'T>
  | Empty
```

Here, a list is either empty (represented by the `Empty` value) or it contains a value of type `'T` followed by another list represented by `List<'T>`. This way, you can create:

```
let nop = Empty                      // Empty list
let oneTwo = Cons(1, Cons(2, Empty)) // List containing 1 and 2
```

So, to answer the question, you will need a very similar definition to the one for `List<'T>`, except that it should not be possible to create an `Empty` list. You can start with something like this:

```
type NonEmptyList<'T> = 
  | Cons of 'T * NonEmptyList<'T>
```

Now that I removed `Empty`, we can no longer create empty lists - but this does not quite do the trick, because now you can never *end* any list. I won't give a full answer to avoid spoilers as I think figuring this out is the point of the exercise, but you will need something like:

```
type NonEmptyList<'T> = 
  | Cons of 'T * NonEmptyList<'T>
  | // One more case here
```

What can the last case be, so that it does not contain another `List<'T>` (and thus lets us end a list), but is not `Empty`, so that we cannot create empty lists?

Comment: I believe that you've accidentally made your definitions non-recursive, so your first attempt actually does solve the problem by relying on the existing `List<_>` type.

Comment: Thanks for replying! I've edited my post to answer your question

Comment: @JoshWilliams Oh no, I made a confusing mistake! I edited my answer - the idea was not to use _list_ at all, but instead to define a new type all from scratch (but I accidentally referred to `List<'T>` in the definition of `NonEmptyList<'T>`). Using an ordinary list would work too - as you did - you just add one more element to ordinary list, to make sure it's non-empty!

Comment: @joahwilliams with your definition, try constructing a list of a few elements. Are you able to?

Comment: Thanks for the replies! I am getting a bit confused due the multiple solutions I got here. @Fyodor, see edit 2. Not sure where 'T is needed for

Comment: @JoshWilliams Try adapting your solution based on my fixed answer - now you have `NonEmptyList<'T>` with a `Cons` case that lets you add element to another non-empty list. You have no way of creating an empty list (which is what we want), but you have no other way of ending a list, which is bad! So, the trick would be to make it possible to create a list with just one element. Then you can create 1) list with one element or 2) list with one element followed by another list

Answer (score 5):

A non-empty list consists of a head and an optional non-empty tail. You can represent such a type as a single-case union:

```
type NEL<'a> = NEL of 'a * NEL<'a> option
let l = NEL(1, Some(NEL(2, None)))
```

or a record type:

```
type NEL<'a> = {head : 'a; tail : NEL<'a> option}
let l = { head = 1; tail = Some({head = 2; tail = None})}
```